# Sylvester–Gallai theorem Proof By Induction

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

While reading about Sylvester–Gallai theorem, I got the simple proof of the theorem using Induction.

Statement:

Given a finite set of points in Euclidian plane such that any line passing through two of the points shall pass through at least one more of them, then all points have to be collinear.

Base case:

Let n=3

Given 3 points, If a line containing two of them passes through one more of them, they are by definition, collinear.

Thus statement #1 is true for n=3.

Step Case

P(k) : Given k points. Assuming that the statement #1 holds true for given set of k points.

P(k+1):
Show that for every k ≥ 3, if P(k) holds, then P(k + 1) also holds.

Here we can say that for a new point (k+1 th) in the same plane to pass through any line passing through two of the points in the k-points set in P(k), then only the newly added point can go through atleast 3 points. If it pass through atleast two of the point then it has to pass through the line passing through all of them.

Hence the only way to expand the given set of k points to a set of k+1 number of points, is to include an external point which is collinear with the existing points.

Hence all k+1 points of the expanded set are collinear.

Thus by principle of induction, (1) is true for all n>=3.

Is this proof complete ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. I don't really understand how you're arguing in your inductive step. Could you spell it out like "Suppose a set $S$ consists of $k + 1$ points, and $S$ satisfies the hypothesis. Then .... Hence $S$ is collinear"?

Comment: In particular I would like to know: what set are you applying the inductive hypothesis to? And how do you know that set satisfies the requirements of the theorem?

Comment: The only way to expand the given set of k point ( which is already collinear ) is to include an external point which is collinear with the existing points. Other wise it will not pass through atleast two of the points in the k points set in P(k). Hence the newly add k+1 element has to collinear with remaining k points. 
I am assuming this is what the author meant !

Comment: OK - it seems like your argument assumes that any set with $k + 1$ points that satisfies the property in the theorem must be formed by adding a point to a set with $k$ points that satisfies the property in the theorem. I think this needs justification!

Comment: Unfortunately, induction proofs are almost guaranteed to fail. Think about it further.  Why does having a set of $k+1$ points that satisfy the condition, doesn't allow us to find a set of $k$ points that satisfy the condition?

Comment: Base class with n =3, So by definition if a linke have to go through 3 points. then it have to collinear. So the stmt #1 is true.

For Induction Hypotheses, let n =k. Assuming the stmt #1 is true. So that any line in the k point set passes through two points will pass through atleast one more point and it will be collinear. 

For n = k + 1, to add the k+1 th point to the true P(k) points, which are collinear. If we add the k+1th point not collinear to existing k points, then there will be a line which doesn't include 3 points from k+1 point set, that will be a line with exact two points.

Comment: To ensure the property the line has to pass through at least 3 point from the k+1 point set, we have to make k+1th point collinear with at least 2 of the points.

But as P(k) k points are already collinear so by making the k+1th point collinear with 2 points in the k point set, which effectively made all other points in k to be collinear with k+1 th point.

Comment: See my writeup. You can't even apply the induction hypothesis, so you don't get that there are $k$ collinear points. $\quad$ Yes, if you could conclude that there are $k$ collinear points, then all $k+1$ points will be collinear.

Comment: thanks @CalvinLin. i will try to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you can't apply the induction hypothesis.

Although you know that the set of $k+1$ points satisfy the conditions, that doesn't mean that you can just throw out 1 point and make the remaining $k$ points still satisfy the condition, as you potentially need that thrown out point to serve as the "another point on the line for some $p_i, p_j$".

Explicit example from the OP (See comments)

> Line AB Containing C
> Line BC Containing D
> Line CD Containing A
> Line DA Contain B,
> And if we remove any one of the points from the set then the condition will fail for one of the line

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am wondering as in the induction step if we already asumes k points satisfy the conditions. So if we remove the k+1 th point the initial k points is already satisfy the condition right ? 

P(k)  - Assuming statement condition is true for k points, So any lines passing through two of the points passes through atleast one more then it is collinear. 

So why it is a problem to throw out the k+1 th point which was added to already k points which satisfied the condition ?

Comment: Oh I think Now I understood the problem, my mistake is where I am assuming in the (K+1) points, k points is already collinear ! Is that the mistake ?

Comment: Your mistake is "as in the induction step if **we already asumes k points satisfy the conditions**". My point is that there need not be $k$ points that satisfy the conditions. Hence, we cannot apply the induction hypothesis to conclude that $k$ points are collinear. $\quad$ You seem to be missing the first statement, which is why I'm stressing it.

Comment: What I meant was - In the induction step for k+1 points, I am assuming k points in that k+1 point set is collinear. And tried to prove that the k+1 th point have to be connected with another 2 points from k point set, and if it is connected with 2 points then it will have to collinear with the remaining points. 

This is where I made the mistake right ? Or is it somewhere else ?

Comment: What I meant was - In the induction step for k+1 points, I am assuming k points in that k+1 point set is collinear. And tried to prove that the k+1 th point have to be connected with another 2 points from k point set, and if it is connected with 2 points then it will have to collinear with the remaining points because I assumed k points is already collinear ( I am assuming this is the mistake I made ) ? . 

This is where I made the mistake right ? Or is it somewhere else ? –

Comment: @ted Read my writeup. You cannot apply the induction hypothesis because you cannot guarantee finding $k$ points such that "any line passing through two of the points shall pass through at least one more of them (these k points, not all $k+1$ points).  $\quad$ As I mentioned, With the (wrong) assumption that there are $k$ collinear points, then yes the $k+1$ point must be collinear. You didn't make a mistake there.

Comment: Sorry, If my comments are confusing. Eng. not my first language. 
Base case for k = 3 - is true and the statement holds 
Induction Hypothesis P(K) is true - Assuming for some set of K points the statement holds. 
Induction Step - To prove P(K+1) - Here I am  - By using the Inducation Hypothesis above for P(K) I am (wrongly) assuming that for the K points in K+1 set the statement holds.

Comment: What I thought was Induction step is where the proof doesnt make sense  ? Because there is no gurantee or no justification is provided, for that set of k points the statement holds. 

But Now I think, If I understood what you meant -  in the induction hypothesis I just can’t say for some k points in the plane ( not all the k point configurations ) the statement holds ? The condition in statement will not be true for all the k points in the plane >

Comment: @ted Right, that's what I wrote up. Can you read through it again and see which line doesn't make sense to you? I think working through the explicit example would help you too.

Comment: Without writing down the explicit example - that when any two points in k point set passes through another one. ( Pi, Pj, P(i+j mod k+1) ) . If we remove any one of the Px, then that all lines passing through 2 should pass though another condition will fail. So unless we didn't given any justification or proof for Pi, Pj pass through any other Pa from the k point set. It will be wrong ? 

Do this proof is an example of following : 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_horses_are_the_same_color

Comment: I tried the explicit example by hand for k = 3, k+1 = 4

A - 1, B - 2, C - 3 , D -4 

      A, B => (1+2)%4 = 3 % 4 = 3, Point C   - So Line passing through A and B pass through C

      B, C => (2 + 3)%4 = 5 % 4 = 1, Point A - Line passing through B and C pass through A 

      C, D => ( 3 + 4)% 4= 7% 4 = 3, Point C -> Here Got I stuck because C is already part of the line then what to do ?

Comment: @ted It is close to the example, but not quite. The horse color example only fails for $n = 2$, and it's clear why "same color" doesn't apply across distinct groups. $\quad$ Right, so for $k = 3$, there is no 3 point set that satisfies the condition. EG In set $\{A, B, C \}$, we have $AC $ passes through $D$ which isn't in our 3-point set. Hence, we cannot apply the induction hypothesis, because there is no 3 point set. $\quad$ As for "then what to do", this is why the (naive) induction solution likely doesn't work. I recommend trying a different approach.

Comment: I think stackoverflow comment messed up my previous comment - What I was trying to explain - I was not able to make the explicit example work doing by hand for k = 3.  I have attached a document to explain what I did. 

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1-oPrEKU_ncNOGT_5ho5GLlFc-UkpfL6a8IqfJOdXRk0

Thanks you for your helps

Comment: @ted Ah true, the $p_i , p_j$ also contains $p_{i+j}$ doesn't work for $j = k+1$. $\quad$ Can you figure out a different construction that won't let us find a 3 point set?

Comment: Yeah - I could construct - Line  AB Containing C
Line BC Containing D
Line CD Containing A
Line DA Contain B, And if we remove any one of the points from the set then the condition will fail for one of the line.

Comment: Hey I have a follow up doubt the proof. I understood why the proof can be wrong in the case where we start with K+1 points compliying to the SG theorem ( line passes through 2 points also passes through 1 more point in the set )

What If I start with induction Hypothesis itself in induction step, We know that set of K points are collinear and adding an external point to the K set to make it a K + 1 set.  So here we can say that to make sure K + 1 th point to pass through 2 points in K set it has to be collinear with all points. Why doing this way is wrong ?

Comment: @ted You can't just assume " What If I start with induction Hypothesis itself in induction step", and ignore the cases where we can't. $\quad$ It boils down to "Given $k+1$ points that satisfy the condition, we cannot guarantee that we could find $k$ points that satisfy the condition." If we could, we are done. But we can't always. So, how do you fix the gap in the proof when there aren't $k$ points that satisfy the condition?

Comment: Thankyou Calvin for the replies.. I understood the issue you have pointed out, it is possible for k+1 points to satisfy the condition and k points in the same set not.   So is it a Flaw in  proving a theorem using induction proof - that we can start from the induction hypothesis. Or is it fundamentally wrong to do it in the case of a proof by induction. I am not able to figure out a absurd statement to prove using this way ( starting from induction hypothesis and extending the points )

Comment: @ted We can start from the induction hypothesis (that if we have $k$ points that satisfy the condition, then they have a certain configuration), that remains valid. $\quad$ The flaw/issue is that we cannot directly apply the induction hypothesis to a set of $k+1$ points. It might be possible that someone comes up with a very clever workaround. $\quad$ I'm unaware of an induction proof to SG (but that doesn't mean that induction could never work).

Comment: To make it clear, So it is valid to create K + 1 points directly from K points which we assumed in the Induction Hypothesis. By create I mean to create K + 1 points set for the Induction step, By extending a set of K points, which we assumed the SG theorem holds via Induction hypothesis, with an external point. I agree that it is forming a gap in proof but is there a rule or logic stopping us from creating the K + 1 points the way I just did. So is it a clever workaround ?

Comment: @ted No. Not at all. Please read again carefully. The IH that we assume to be true is: if a set of k points satisfy the conditions, then they have the configuration. $\quad$ You may not "tcreate K + 1 points directly from K points which we assumed in the Induction Hypothesis". The IH isn't "From any K+1 points, there exists K points that satisfy the condition". That's the missing logic which you seem to think is the IH. It is not. Write out the Induction proof one small step at a time. $\quad$ At this point, I'm just repeating what I've said numerous times, so I'm not sure how else to help.

Comment: Thank you for the patience... https://docs.google.com/document/d/1lko9x_B_LnIbrV-H8jY9h72FgBhaDIa3xznACqqPIyU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152252/discussion-between-ted-and-calvin-lin).

Comment: This was my doubt in my last chat : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4888147/proof-by-induction-how-to-apply-induction-hypothesis