# Proof By Induction - How to apply Induction Hypothesis?

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Suppose I am trying to prove a theorem using Induction by proof. Usual induction proof by induction examples follow the following steps :

1. First show that Base case is true, let's say P(0) is true
2. Then Assume P(K) is true
3. Then in the inductive step we start with P(K+1) and break it into P(K) + ( Some Things) else to show P(K) is true.

I am wondering can we do it the other way around. In the inductive step can we start from the P(K) and then we add something to the P(K) to make it P(K+1) by following the conditions of the proof. Then prove that the statement holds true for P(K+1).

For an example proof :

Let's take the [Sylvester–Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem).

Given a finite set of points in Euclidian plane such that any line passing through two of the points shall pass through at least one more of them, then all points have to be collinear.

1. First we show that P(3) is true, base case
2. Induction Hypothesis P(K): Assumed for K set of points the statement holds. Every line passes through two points also pass through a third point in the set. K points are collinear.
3. In the induction step I am adding an external point to set and making sure the added point follows the conditions to satisfy the SG theorem. That is for an external point in the same plane to pass through any line passing through two of the points in the K-points set in P(K), it has to pass through the line passing through all of them. Hence all K+1 points are collinear.K

[Additional Explanations and Context on the SG theorem proof (wrong) specifically. Check Calvin Lin Answer's comments for the discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4874159/sylvester-gallai-theorem-proof-by-induction/4874174)

Comment: You are also assuming $P(K)$ is true.

Comment: I don't think that I like your step (3) at the start.  You need to assume that $P(K)$ is true, and then use *whatever tools you have available* to prove that $P(K+1)$ is true.  Sometimes, this involves starting with $P(K+1)$ and somehow reducing it to $P(K)$; other times, it involves starting with $P(K)$ and "bulking it up" to $P(K+1)$; and yet other times, neither of the above really describes the structure of the proof.

Comment: Your step 3 is *not* the usual way of doing.  The set way of doing it is: Assume $P(k)$ is true as a given and show that therefore $P(k+1)$ is true.  You can do that any consistent and logical way you want. If it works by taking $P(k+1)=P(k)+ stuff$ that is certainly *a* way to do it but it sure as serbert isn't the "usual" way to do it.  Math isn't parlor games where you follow rules because someone says they look nice.  If logic says something is true then... it is true.

Comment: For the induction step, you assume that the SG theorem is true for all sets of $k$ points, and you have to prove it for **all** sets of $k+1$ points. How do you know that **every** set of $k+1$ points, which satisfies the SG condition, contains a set of $k+1$ points which also satisfies the SG condition?

Comment: **Theorem.** Every graph with no isolated points is connected. **Proof by induction.** It's true for graphs with $1$ (vacuously) or $2$ or $3$ points. Induction step: Suppose a graph with $n$ points and no isolates is connected. Add an external point. If the external point is not isolated, then the resulting $n+1$-point graph is still connected. **Q.E.D.???**

Comment: **Theorem.** If a set of $n$ points satisfies the condition "each point of the set is collinear with (at least) $2$ other points of the set, the the whole set lies on a line. **Proof by induction.** It's true for $n\le4$. For the induction step, assume that it's true for $n$ points. Let $S$ be a set of $n$ points which satisfies the condition, so the whole set $S$ lies on a line $L$. Add an external point $p$. If the condition still holds, so the point $p$ is collinear with two points of $S$, the $p$ also lies on the line $S$. **Q.E.D.???**

Comment: Is Assuming P(K) is true wrong ? I thought in the Induction hypothesis we can assume that the statement holds for K and try to solve for K + 1. 
 
Non English speaking person here, I need some time to understand the other comments or not even able to understand whether it is sarcasm  ....

Comment: Tor the induction step, you assume that $T(k)$ is true, and you have to prove that $T(k+1)$ is true. If $T(k)$ says that **every** $k$-set satisfying some condition C has some property P , then the statement $T(k+1)$ that you have to prove says that **every** $(k+1)$-point set which satisfies C has property P. In order to prove a statement about **every** $(k+1)$-point set satisfying C, you have to start: "Let $S$ be **any** $(k+1)$-point set satisfying C, **not** "Let $S$ be a $(k+1)$-point set obtained in a certain way."

Comment: For additional context (which I wish OP would add), I had a [long exchange with OP here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4874159/sylvester-gallai-theorem-proof-by-induction/4874174), but failed to make them understand the nuance of their misconception. OP seems stuck on thinking that the Induction Hypothesis implies "From any K+1 points, there exists K points that satisfy the condition", despite being told that 1/ That's not what the IH is, and 2/ That's not true of sets of K+1 points. I'm not sure how else to phrase that (and that seems to be the difficulty that other users are have)

Comment: @CalvinLin I have added this question link in the comment secion for the first question.

Comment: @ted I wish you added it to THIS question, so that others have the context when looking at THIS question. Even if you do not believe what I'm saying, at least a note of "I've already tried to clear my doubt here, but I don't see where they are coming from", would help provide context to others. $\quad$ I'm not sure to what extent my summary in the previous comment correctly represents your current understanding, so that context would be helpful.

Comment: @CalvinLin I will add the question in this question. Please don't misunderstood me, It is not that I don't  believe, I was not able to understand why starting with Induction hypothesis could be wrong ? I thought I understood why starting with Induction hypothesis fails to cover all the cases in the proof I have shared earlier. 

But I was not sure of whether doing that will be always wrong not not. Starting from Induction Hypothesis and extending. Thank you for all your comments and help in the previous question.

Comment: 1/ Please state (just the) Induction Hypothesis. IE I claim the the IH is "For a set of k points, if they satisfy the condition, then they form a straight line configuration".(which is your point 2). That is valid so far.  $\quad$ 2/ "why starting with Induction hypothesis fails to cover all the cases " This is not quite it. More accurately, it's that the IH cannot be applied to all cases of $K+1$ points. To those where it can be applied, the desired conclusion is true. To those where it cannot be applied, we will need to figure out a way to fix it (but we're unable to fix the gap thus far).

Comment: What I understood (and thought right ) - In the normal Induction proof way, In induction step I will be taking K + 1 points and make sure that every line passes through 2 points also passes through a 3rd one in the K + 1 set. Now If I try to seperate K +1 point to K  set of points and another point. That K set points is no gurantee of satisfying the conditions we have made sure earlier ( Line passing through  2 points also passes through 3rd point), Because the the point which got seperated might be 3rd point of a line which passes through 2 points in k set. So can't aply IH here.

Comment: So based on the above discussions - I saw examples on why extending Induction Hypothesis is an issue and also couple of comments saying it is also an approach in induction proof ( if it is right or covers the gaps ? ).. So this is depend on the problem or statement we are tackling ? In the case of sum of N natural numbers if I start with the Induction hypothesis (n*(n+1)/2) in the induction step and adding a new value n+1. Should not have caused an issue ?

Comment: For SG, the induction hypothesis $P(K)$ is a conditional statement: "for any set of $K$ points, if they satisfy some condition $Q$, then they are collinear." Then to prove $P(K+1)$ (also a conditional statement), the proof starts with assuming the antecedent: "given some set of $K+1$ points that satisfy the condition $Q$". But your attempt quickly claims that "there exists a subset of $K$ points that satisfy the condition $Q$" in order to apply $P(K)$, and a criticism here is that this step is not trivial.

Comment: @Ѕᴀᴀᴅ This question got answered for my question - about how to use the induction hypothesis - Like whether can I start with an inductino hypothesis and extend it or not ?